# Permission actions-on-google not showing up

Tags: permissions, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I'm facing a problem when asking the user to grant a permission.
I don't know why but the same code I used until 4 days ago is no longer working.

```
app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', conv => {
conv.data.requestedPermission = 'NAME';

if(!conv.user.storage.name) {
  console.log('name non esiste');
    return conv.ask(new Permission({
        context: 'Benvenuto',
        permissions: conv.data.requestedPermission,
    }));
}
});
```

Here's an example, when my action starts, it just says "Demo stopped working.." (and it enters the if because I can see the log message).
and I get the same result with any permission request in my code. As I said before, the same code was working some days ago. Could you help me?

Comment: Do you see any other logs like a server problem?

Comment: Hey Nick, thank you, I solved the problem :) Basically I didn't remember I set the action to be "for family" in the Actions Console and you can't ask for any permission in that kind of action

Comment: Great! It can be helpful to post that as an answer to help anyone else to runs into the same error.

Comment: @Joaquim if the problem has been solved the correct course of action is you or the OP converting the solution to an answer (and accepting it by clicking the green check mark). It is not correct to edit a question to include a solution in it.

Comment: As Nick and @bad_coder have properly commented, it would be great if you could post an answer with the solution to your problem so that the community may benefit from it.